# Blur.js with Amazon S3 Stored Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, blur

How can I use external images with blur.js?  I have images stored on Amazon S3 and I'd like to use those in my web app but I don't know if this is possible because canvas doesn't seem to allow for external images.  Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Actually, doing the blur on the server side and then sending the image would be ideal.  Any suggestions in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

In service of your comment that server-side blurring with PHP would be preferable- I would suggest using ImageMagick with the ImageMagick extension.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

There are several different blur options available but just plain blur is the simplest:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.blurimage.php

For blur.js- You might just need to set your S3 bucket's CORS settings.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors